# Exterior derivative is linear PDO of order $1$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am using [this definition of PDO on page 19](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf).

I want to verify my understanding by the example of exetior derivative.

---

The exterior derivative $d:\Omega^p(M) \rightarrow \Omega^{p+1}(M)$ can locally be given by, for a $p$-form, 
$$ w = \sum_{|I|=p} a_I dx_I \mapsto \sum_{|I|=p} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial{a_I}}{\partial x_j} dx_j \wedge dx_I$$

where $I$ subset of $\{0,\ldots, n \}$, $n = \dim M$.

> Claim: $d$ is a linear PDO of order $1$.

---

The definition of PDO requiries that locally $P$ looks like 
$$f \mapsto \sum _{|\alpha| \le k } A^\alpha (y) \frac{\partial^{\alpha}}{\partial x_\alpha} f(y).$$

---

So I think it is not obvious what $A^\alpha$s are where $\alpha = (0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$, $1$ in the $j$th position.

---

1. In these coordinates. $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_j}$ 
   is $\sum_{|I|=p} \frac{\partial a_I}{\partial x_j} dx_I$
2. Depending on $n$, $A^\alpha$ is  a matrix with values in $\pm1$, $0$.

---

Is my line of thought correct?

Comment: Sorry, it is the one in page 19. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts look correct.  I'll just (attempt) to set the record straight.

In local coordinates $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, we can write
$$d\left(\sum_{|I|=p}a_Idx_I\right)=\sum_{j=1}^ndx_j\wedge\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\sum_{|I|=p}a_Idx_I\right]=\sum_{j=1}^nA^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\sum_{|I|=p}a_Idx_I\right) .$$
We have $n$ different $\binom{n}{p+1}\times\binom{n}{p}$ matrices $A^1,\ldots A^n$, which we can conveniently index by $p-$ and $(p+1)-$element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  For $I,J\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $|I|=p$, $|J|=p+1$, the $(J,I)$-entry of $A^j$ will be $\pm 1$ if $J=I\cup\{j\}$ (with the sign of the entry depending on $I$ in the obvious way), and $0$ otherwise.